# Can the vertices of a "transformed" polytope be computed in terms of vertices of the original polytope?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, linear-programming, polytopes

Given an initial polytope bounded by $n$ inequalities $Ex \leq f$  where $E \in \mathcal{R}^{n \times n} $ and $f \in \mathcal{R}^n$, assume we know the set of vertices of this (bounded) polytope.

Now, consider a transformation (matrix $H \in \mathcal{R}^{n \times m}$) composed of m orthonormal columns.  Consider a transformed set of inequalities given by   $\tilde{E}q \leq \tilde{f}$ where $\tilde{E}= EH$ and $\tilde{E} \in \mathcal{R}^{n \times m}$. And, $\tilde{f}, q \in \mathcal{R}^m$

Can the vertices of the new set of inequalities, $\tilde{E} \leq \tilde{f}$ be computed using the vertices of  $Ex \leq f$ ?

Comment: What is q and has $\tilde{f}$ a special construction related to $f$?

Comment: $f$ and $\tilde{f}$ are related by an additive constant

Comment: Do you really mean $E\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$? This would imply that there is exactly one vertex if $E$ is invertible and otherwise none.